# Compiler error MSB3073 in PCL installation

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to install [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) API by following the instructions in [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/UnaNancyOwen/59319050d53c137ca8f3). I am working with windows 10 and visual studio 2015. I am new to C++ and so I have made many basic mistakes.

When building `All_BUILD` project in Debug configuration i get 116 successful. However I do get errors when building in Release configuration.

when building `INSTALL` project in Debug configuration I get:

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:46 (file):
117>    file INSTALL cannot read symlink "C:/Program
117>    Files/boost/boost_1_64_0/bin.v2/test-symlink" to duplicate at "C:/Program
117>    Files/PCL/3rdParty/Boost/boost/boost_1_64_0/bin.v2/test-symlink".
117>
117>
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
117>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
========== Rebuild All: 116 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Obviously I have made sure `C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_64_0/bin.v2/test-symlink` exist.

All I could find as a solution was to run visual studio as administrator (which I already am doing). I have found [this post](http://www.pclcn.org/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=884) in chinise saying I have to edit some windows administrator privileges. I do not speak Chinese and I have used google translate. I do not fully understand what or how to do this.

- Any idea how to solve this? Is there another approach?
- Does errors in `BUILD_ALL` in Release configuration influence the `INSTALL` in Debug configuration?

Comment: What does your "other problems i have solved" have to do with your question?  Stack Overflow is not for blog posts.

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is a place to ask questions and get answers.  If you want to share knowledge, start a blog.  I have removed the irrelevant parts from your question.

Comment: None of it is relevant to your question.  Okay, if you want to share knowledge, *answer questions*. Stack Overflow is not a blog.